# OrmLite Contains() not working as expected

Tags: servicestack

If I try to get all users with a certain role like this:

```
 _db.Select<UserAuthCustom>(x => x.Roles.Contains("Bloggers"));
```

Then it works as expected and returnsthe users.

If I try to do it with the query builder like so:

```
        var q = _db.From<UserAuthCustom>()
            .Where(x => x.Roles.Contains("Bloggers"))
            .Limit(1);
```

Then it throws an exception because it thinks "bloggers" is a column and has translated this into into something like `WHERE bloggers IN (null)`.

Is it possible to do something like `LIKE '%\"Blogger\"%'` on the blobbed field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use typed queries against blobbed columns like the `Roles` collection which are blobbed in the table using the [configured complex type serializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#pluggable-complex-type-serializers) which defaults to [JSV format](https://docs.servicestack.net/jsv-format) for all RDBMS's except for PostgreSQL which uses JSON.

If you want to perform server-side queries on the Roles collection I'd recommend [persisting them in distinct tables](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#extending-userauth-tables):

```
container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c =>
    new OrmLiteAuthRepository<UserAuthCustom, UserAuthDetails>(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()) {
        UseDistinctRoleTables = true
    });
```

That way you can use a standard join query to select all users in a specific role:

```
var q = db.From<UserAuthCustom>()
      .Join<UserAuthRole>((u,r) => r.UserAuthId = u.Id)
      .Where<UserAuthRole>(x => x.Role == "Bloggers");
```

Alternatively you would need to create a Custom SQL query to query against the blobbed Roles column as a string, e.g:

```
q.Where("Roles LIKE @role", new { role = "%Blogger%" });
```

Or using [typed column names](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-columnt-and-tablet-apis) in Custom SQL Expressions:

```
q.Where(q.Column<UserAuthCustom>(x => x.Roles) + " LIKE @role, 
    new { role = "%Blogger%" });
```